# c# castle windsor container.Register issue

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I am new to using castle windsor.  I have it set up and functioning correctly in my MVC4 app.  For brevity the impacted layout of my solution is:

*Entities.dll*
  - `ICompanyRepository`

*DAL.dll*
  - `Company` : `ICompanyRepository`

Basically I have a bunch of classes and interfaces set up like above so I can switch out the DAL if need be with another repository.  I have currently registered the class and interface with Castle Windsor by using the following:

```
container.Register(Component.For<Entities.ICompanyRepository>().ImplementedBy<DAL.Company>().LifestyleTransient());
```

My interface and class that implements it are in separate projects and therefore dlls in my project.  What I would like to do but cannot figure out is to use one blanket configuration line like the above:

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("Entities"));
```

I have tried many different combinations but I can't get it working.  Any ideas?  I am open to loading from a config file if that is better option.

Answer (score 1):

I assume all your repositories are implementing a common interface such IRepository, if not you should do so not just for IoC purpose...

that you can use following registration in order to register all component based on a common interface.
Installer should be located in the entry-point project so it should be able to see any other projects/dll.

```
container.Register(Classes
.FromAssemblyNamed("DAL")//assembly containing concrete types
.BasedOn(typeof(IRepository<>))
.WithService.DefaultInterfaces()//concrete will be associated(windosr configuration) with closest interface
.Configure(c => c.YourPolicystrategy()));
```